# jQuery load meta tags content from youtube

Tags: jquery

I want to load the meta tags from youtube when a user types in a link and presses submit.
i have tried the follwing:

```
<div id="container">
<center>
<input type="text" id="url" />
<div><a href="#" id="loadnow">Load youtube  video</a></div>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="title"></div>
        <div id="info"></div>
        <div id="link"></div>
        <div id="video"></div>
    </div>
</center>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#loadnow').click(function(){
    var url = $('#url').val();
    $('#wrap').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#title').load(url + 'meta[itemprop=name]').attr("content");// second try
        $('#info').load('url meta[itemprop=description]'); //first try
        $('#link').load('url meta[itemprop=url]');
        var videoUrl = $('#video').load('url meta[itemprop=name]');
        $('#video').html("<iframe width='560' height='315' src='"+videoUrl+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
        $('#wrap').fadeIn();
    });
});
});
</script>
```

How do i load those meta tags from youtube and output them to the user ?
i cant find anything about it on google.
EDIT: it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

So this is almost valid: `$('#title').load(url + 'meta[itemprop=name]').attr("content");`, the variable is being concocted into the rest of the string but you need a space between the `url` variable and the rest of the string so jQuery knows that `meta[itemprop=name]` is not part of the URL:

```
$('#title').load(url + ' meta[itemprop=name]').attr("content");
```

Now you're going to run into the issue that you are requesting content from another domain. So you will either need to use JSONP or create a server-side proxy that gathers the remote information for you.

### Update

I think what's going to help you the most is to either setup a proxy to scrape the information from the YouTube website or **even better** you can use one of the YouTube APIs: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html

Comment: Thank you! ans well yes i thought i would be blocked out.
i have tried an scim their API though but i couldn't find something about getting the meta tags. also i have been trying to see what facebook do, and yes they do a json request.. so maybe i should do that too :)

Answer (score 0):

You try to access content on a different domain via AJAX. That is not possbile due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).